# Fiz alterações na branch errada, como reverter as alterações nesta branch sem apagar o que foi feito?

Tags: git

Estava trabalhando em uma branch chamada task-1. Sem querer, mudei de branch e fiz diversas modificações na branch que se chamava task-2. Como faço para reverter as alterações na branch task-2 sem precisar fazer commit e apagar tudo o que foi feito?

Comment: Onde estão essas alterações? Você já commitou ou estão na *staging area*?

Comment: Não commitei. Não está na staging.

Comment: Então é só trocar pra branch certa.

Comment: Pode executar `git stash`, efetuar o *checkout* para o branch correto e aplicar com `git stash apply`.

Comment: Ou então `git stash pop`, que limpa o `stash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você:

- Tinha arquivos modificados em uma branch task-1 e
- Foi direto para a `task-2` e continuou alterando estes (e outros) arquivos achando que estava na `task-1`
- Deseja manter estas alterações na `task-1` e remover elas da `task-2`

Você tem as seguintes opções:

## Voltar para a task-1

Simplesmente volte para a `task-1`.

```
git checkout task-1
```

O git vai carregar todas as alterações da `task-2` para a `task-1`. Ao commitar tudo na `task-1` e voltar para `task-2`, verá que a branch `task-2` estará intacta

## Guarde as alterações da task-2 e as aplique na task-1

Ainda na task-2, use o comando:

```
git stash -u # o -u inclui os arquivos que criou, também
```

Vá para a branch `task-1` e aplique o comando para descarregar as alterações:

```
git checkout task-1
git stash pop
```

## Usar o git diff

Na branch `task-2` você pode criar um arquivo com todas as alterações:

```
git diff HEAD >> arquivo_todas_alteracoes.diff
```

Limpar as modificações da branch:

```
git reset HEAD . # mover todas alterações do stage
git clean -f -d  # limpar todas as alterações
```

Ir até a branch `task-1` e aplicar as alteraçõe do arquivo diff:

```
git checkout task-1
git apply arquivo_todas_alteracoes.diff
```